# C++ entry points not showing up in node.js profiling output

Tags: node.js, macos, profiling, v8

When running `node --prof <command>`, then later `node --prof-process` on macOS, my profiling output no-longer shows any of the C++ entry points, leading to a lot of unaccounted-for gaps in my profiling data. Changed around the same time, I now just see the `node` binary in these profiling trees where it wasn't showing up before, so it's like the profiler is no-longer able to "dive in" to the internals of node.

I think this started when trying to improve dtrace permissions with `csrutil`, but I've restored things back to their factory settings and this still happens.

What causes C++ entry points to not show up in traces? Is there a way to fix the issue?

**Update**:

Just tried turning off SIP entirely with `csrutil disable` (which is a bad thing to do), and the problem persists, so maybe SIP is a red herring here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amazing wizards in the node.js github issues [figured this out](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/29804).

In short, I learned that two commands are used by the profiler on macOS: `c++filt` and `nm`. When I tried reporting which versions of those commands I had installed, I got this message back for `nm`:

```
» nm --version                                                                                                                                           
Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please run “sudo xcodebuild -license” and then retry this command.
```

Apparently the requirement of accepting the license was added, perhaps after an upgrade, and this was blocking the ability for the profiler to look up and demangle C++ symbols. After I accepted the license, the profiler started working normally again.

Hopefully this helps others running across the same scenario.